# JQuery Datepicker doesnt work on iOS devices but works on Windows and Android

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, safari, datepicker, datetimepicker

I was working on my site last morning and I even tested it out in Safari and on my iphone and I'm pretty sure that the Datepicker which shows up when you click **Full Calendar** under **Choose Date** section is working. Now a client sent a message 2 hours ago saying that the calendar is not showing up once the **FULL CALENDAR** button was clicked. I tried it on my mac and it's working in chrome and other browsers except Safari. I also tried it on my iphone tonight and found out that it's not working for both safari and chrome browser.

Here's the link to the site: http://www.localflorist.ie/adonis/zeus

Please help me, I already spent 4 hours trying to fix this problem.

:(

Thanks a lot!

Header code for CSS import:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.bmtester.com/assets/css/style.css?ver=1468931601">


<script>
  var loadDeferredStyles = function() {
    var addStylesNode = document.getElementById("deferred-styles");
    var replacement = document.createElement("div");
    replacement.innerHTML = addStylesNode.textContent;
    document.body.insertBefore(replacement, document.body.firstChild)
    addStylesNode.parentElement.removeChild(addStylesNode);
  };
  var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
  if (raf) raf(function() { window.setTimeout(loadDeferredStyles, 0); });
  else window.addEventListener('load', loadDeferredStyles);
</script>
```

Body code which activates the calendar on Click

```
<li>
 <label for="date-delivery" class="full-calendar">
   <input type="radio" name="date_delivery" class="form-control bm-rounded" id="date-delivery" value="07/24/2016" >
   <span class="hover"></span>
    <span class="dd-md-der">
    <span id="full-cal-day">Full</span>
    <span id="full-cal-month">Calendar</span>
   </span>
 </label>
</li>
```

JS Code for calendar

```
$(".full-calendar").click(function(){ $("#date-delivery").datetimepicker("show"); });
  $('#date-delivery').datepicker({
    setDate : $(this).val(),
    minDate:3,
    datepicker:true,
    scrollMonth:false,
    timepicker:false,
    format:'m/d/Y'
  });
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When you need help with debugging, you should provide the relevant parts of your code in the question directly so that others don't need to look for it in your sources. So please do it.

Comment: @YakovL thanks for the suggestion, edited the question w/ the codes now.